# Blacken out screen while a request is being processed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some controls on a page with some buttons. When a button is clicked, a request is made to the server, and on receiving the response, the button text updates (On/Off). The way I have it now, is that the button when clicked, remains active and the user is able to click it multiple times. But this causes the requests to pile up one after the other without being executed, which ultimately freezes or slows down the page and also the server. I want the screen to blacken out on the initial button click and remain so till the request is over with some result and only after that the user gets to click the buttons again. How do I incorporate something like a modal window in this case with the message that the request is being processed?

Help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just set an appropriate element or elements to either disabled or hidden. Then when the request is processed, enable them all again in the callback.

Comment: Create a black / transparent (using RGBA) overlay div, then use `beforeSend` ajax event to show it and `.always()` event to hide it.

Comment: Some code would be useful ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes recently i have this type of issue.To fixed this you need to add a loader which will show at time of processing of Ajax
Add this in a your page:-

```
 <div id="blockDiv" class="hide">
    <div class="" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; text-align: center; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border: 3px solid rgb(170, 170, 170); width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0%; background: rgb(20, 14, 51) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; opacity: 0.5; z-index: 1004; cursor: wait; right: 0px;"></div>
    <div class="blockUI blockMsg blockPage " style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; top: 50%; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border: 3px solid rgb(170, 170, 170); font-weight: normal; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 20px; left: 35%; text-align: center; z-index: 999999 ! important; position: fixed; width: 30%;"><img src="http://deepakkit.xtgem.com/files/loading.gifjsessionidURgz41CHGWcq8M1BI6qdZQ.gif" style="height:25px;">Just a moment</div>
</div>
```

Add this css:-

```
.hide{
        display: none;
    }
```

In Ajax add:-

```
 beforeSend : function() {
                    $('#blockDiv').removeClass('hide');
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('#blockDiv').addClass('hide');
                },
```

Then our issue will be fixed.

Comment: no inline css!! its bad practice - move to css file

Comment: still - show it in the `this css` section and add a class in the html part - this will only encourage bad practice for new-to-coding peeps who come along and see the answer

Answer (score 1):

Like i said in my comment, you could create an absolute overlay div, hidden by default.

Then show it on `beforeSend:` Ajax option and hide it on `.always()` event.

Check the example below:

```js
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('.overlay').fadeIn();
    }
    //if using jQuery < 3.0, remove always and use this
    //,complete: function() {
    //   $('.overlay').fadeOut();
    //}
  }).always(function() {
    alert('I have finished!');
    $('.overlay').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: a note rather than critique - background-color: can be shortened to background

Comment: Changed it! Thanks for the note. :)